# How to get the promise value in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to render multiple images, stored on firebase, on a single page.

This is the function to get the image url:

```
async getTokenImage(fileName) {
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref('token/' + fileName);
    const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    console.log('in here')
    return url
}
```

This is the function call:

```
<div
     class="card-img-top" 
     style={{
        backgroundColor: '#'+token.color, 
        backgroundImage: 'url('+this.getTokenImage(token.fileName).then((value) => {return value})+')'
     }}></div>
```

console logging the "value" gives the needed image url  
[image]

but returning the "value" gives nothing. 
for the sake of testing, I have done this:

```
let image = this.getTokenImage(token.fileName).then((result) => {return result})
console.log(image)
```

which results in: 
[image]

So how do I get the image url within the initial function call?

Part of grandfather component:

```
<MintedTokens
    account={this.state.account} 
    contract={this.state.contract} 
    tokens={this.state.tokens} />
```

Father component:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./minted-tokens.scoped.css";

import MultipleMintedTokens from './multiple-minted-tokens.js';
import SingleMintedTokens from './single-minted-token.js';

class MintedTokens extends React.Component {

render() {
    const color = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
    let display
    if(color == undefined) {
        display = <MultipleMintedTokens 
                    account={this.props.account}    
                    tokens={this.props.tokens}></MultipleMintedTokens>
    } else {
        display = <SingleMintedTokens
                    account={this.props.account} 
                    color={color} 
                    tokens={this.props.tokens}></SingleMintedTokens>
    }
    return (
        <div class="Minted-Token">
            {display}
        </div>
    );
   }
 }
 export default MintedTokens;
```

Child component (where the multiple images need to be rendered):

```
import React from 'react';
import ether from '../../assets/ether.svg'
import firebase from "../../firebase.js"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class MultipleMintedTokens extends React.Component {

async getTokenImage(fileName) {
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref('token/' + fileName);
    const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    console.log('in here')
    return url
}

render() {
    return (
        <div class="welcome minted-tokens">
            <h1 class="">Minted Tokens</h1>
            <div class="row">
                {this.props.tokens.map((token, key) => {
                    let name = '',
                        description = ''
                    if(token.to == this.props.account) {
                        token.name.length >= 17 ? name = token.name.slice(0,17) + '...' : name = token.name
                        token.description.length >= 28 ? description = token.description.slice(0,29) + '...' : description = token.description

                        let image = this.getTokenImage(token.fileName).then((result) => {return result})
                        console.log(image)
                        
                        return (
                            <Link to={token.tokenURI} key={key}>
                                <div class='token-id'>{token.id}</div>
                                <div class="card card-width">
                                    <div
                                        class="card-img-top" 
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: '#'+token.color, 
                                            backgroundImage: 'url('+this.getTokenImage(token.fileName).then((value) => {return value})+')'
                                        }}></div>
                                    <h5 class="card-header" style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#'+token.color,
                                        color: '#'+token.fontColor}}>{name}</h5>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p class="card-text">{description}</p>
                                        <div class="foot-of-card">
                                            <span class="row price-row">
                                                <img src={ether} alt="ether" class="icon" />
                                                <p class="card-text">{token.price}</p>
                                            </span>
                                            <p class="card-text datetime">{token.dateTime}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        )
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MultipleMintedTokens;
```

Comment: `.then((thing) => { return thing; })` doesn't do anything useful, the result is still a _promise_ of the value.

Comment: You need to make a render in order to update your DOM after the promise is response. Are you using stateless components ? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @rigojr yes, it's a stateless component, the needed data is being passed by props.

Comment: @RahulMehta can you post the father component and its child, the `this` keyword should only be used on class component, I just want to fully read in order to let you know where you can render.

Comment: @rigojr It's actually grandfather, father and child in this particular case. I have added the codes for the three of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not test it well but you can try the following:

Add:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        urlImgs: [],
      };
    }
...
  componentDidMount() {
    const { tokens } = this.props;
    const promiseArray = tokens.map((token) => getTokenImage(token.fileName));
    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(valueArray => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          urlImgs: valueArray
        }))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
...
backgroundImage: `url(${urlImgs[key] ?? null})`
```

All Code:

```
class MultipleMintedTokens extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        urlImgs: [],
      };
    }

  async getTokenImage(fileName) {
      const ref = firebase.storage().ref('token/' + fileName);
      const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      console.log('in here')
      return url
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { tokens } = this.props;
    const promiseArray = tokens.map((token) => getTokenImage(token.fileName));
    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(valueArray => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          urlImgs: valueArray
        }))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    const { urlImgs } = this.state;
    return (
      <div class="welcome minted-tokens">
        <h1 class="">Minted Tokens</h1>
        <div class="row">
          {this.props.tokens.map((token, key) => {
            let name = '',
            description = ''
            if(token.to == this.props.account) {
              token.name.length >= 17 ? name = token.name.slice(0,17) + '...' : name = token.name
              token.description.length >= 28 ? description = token.description.slice(0,29) + '...' : description = token.description
              let image = this.getTokenImage(token.fileName).then((result) => {return result})
              console.log(image)
              return (
                <Link to={token.tokenURI} key={key}>
                  <div class='token-id'>{token.id}</div>
                  <div class="card card-width">
                    <div
                        class="card-img-top"
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: '#'+token.color,
                            backgroundImage: `url(${urlImgs[key] ?? null})`
                        }}></div>
                    <h5 class="card-header" style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#'+token.color,
                        color: '#'+token.fontColor}}>{name}</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">{description}</p>
                        <div class="foot-of-card">
                            <span class="row price-row">
                                <img src={ether} alt="ether" class="icon" />
                                <p class="card-text">{token.price}</p>
                            </span>
                            <p class="card-text datetime">{token.dateTime}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              )
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default MultipleMintedTokens;
```

if you have React with version > 16.8, I advice you to start using Stateless Components and Hooks. And read about the lifecycle of React and the render method [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

Comment: Thank you! This is works perfectly. I did think of using the state in this case but I was worried if it had to load dozens of images then it might be a hit to the efficiency?

Comment: Nice!! Remember that the first time that the component get mount, those images will not have the url because the promise will be responding and that take sometime, on this case will be a few renders since we are using a `Promise.all()`. Remember, read about the lifecycle, is very important!